# Europe: Central Academic CS Job Market Service like CRA?

Tags: computer-science, job-search, faculty-application, europe, online-resource

When searching for faculty positions in CS, I find the service http://cra.org/ads/ very useful. There you can find many job ads from North America based institutions. Is there any similar service for Europe?

Comment: This question might need to be more specific about the desired career level - research assistant, postdoc, professor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any similar service for Europe?

Unfortunately the answer to this question is **no**. The closest equivalent, at least in the German-speaking area, is [Academics.com](https://www.academics.com). I am not aware of a similarly complete portal for the rest of Europe.

Additionally, the most complete list for the German-speaking area is definitely the newsletter sent out monthly by the ["deutschen Hochschulverband"](http://www.hochschulverband.de/cms1/) (essentially the union of German university teachers). This list has rather official character and is pretty much complete for the area. However, you need to be a member to receive this newsletter, and one can only become a member by having been employed in an academic post at a German university.

*(or you know a member and ask him to forward you the newsletter each month)*