# Website for professorship positions in Germany?

Tags: job-search, professorship, job, germany

Is there any website for professorship positions in Germany? I find few websites, but they don't cover most of the universities. There are more up-to-date advertisements on the website of universities, but it is very time consuming to check them one by one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have covered this very recently in the answer to a [related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61046/europe-central-academic-cs-job-market-service-like-cra/61048#61048).

Firstly, there is is [Academics.com](https://www.academics.com). It is a free service that should have you covered to a large extend. As a bonus, it is not *strictly* for offers in Germany, but also has some professorships in neighbouring countries (although coverage for those is rather spotty).

The most complete list is the newsletter sent out monthly by the ["deutschen Hochschulverband"](http://www.hochschulverband.de/cms1/), which is the union of German university teachers. This list is pretty much complete for Germany, but it does not have any info on professorships anywhere else. You need to be a member to receive this newsletter, and one can only become a member by having been employed in an academic post at a German university before. If you currently work in Germany (e.g, as a PhD student or postdoc), you are either already a member or can easily become one.

Comment: Professorship positions in Germany are nearly always announced in the newspaper *Zeit* and on the corresponding website http://jobs.zeit.de/ (where you can create a filter for just these positions and subscribe to a weekly newsletter); this is also often true for positions in Austria and Switzerland. Unofficially, the [Mathematics Jobs Wiki](http://notable.math.ucdavis.edu/wiki/Mathematics_Jobs_Wiki) also does a fairly good job of tracking open positions (as well as following up with lists, offers, accepted positions etc., but this information is often based on hearsay and much less reliable).

Comment: Digging deeper, jobs.zeit.com and academics.com share the same database, but offer a different interface. Note that universities actively have to notify one or the other of their announcements, but they usually do (at least for the *Zeit*). Also, the DHV is not the union, but the professional association of university teachers. To get the newsletter, you have to be a *dues paying* member of this association, which is not automatic and officially only open to professors or lecturers (but less officially also to "soon to be" such, i.e., late career postdocs).

Comment: You can [pay them](https://www.hochschulverband.de/cms1/dhv-dienstleistungsvertrag.html) to send you the newsletter even if you don't qualify, though. (Currently, it costs you 90 Euro per year.)